# How do you schedule a task (using schtasks.exe) to run once and delete itself?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-task-scheduler

I want to schedule a task from the command prompt (using `schtasks.exe`) to run once and delete the task entry from the Task Scheduler Library after completion.

After looking through the usage guide, I settled on this command:

```
schtasks /create /TN SomeTaskName /TR "notepad.exe" /SC ONCE /ST 12:00 /Z
```

...but that gives me this error (I'm running Windows 10)

```
ERROR: The task XML is missing a required element or attribute.
(40,4):EndBoundary:
```

Looking it up online, I found out about [this KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2004151) that suggests using the **`/V1`** switch to get rid of the error but on adding **`/V1`** I am asked for the current user password to schedule the task. I don't want that.

Is there any way to schedule a task to be executed once and then deleted from the task library after execution completes?

I've tried this, but it didn't work:

```
schtasks /create /TN SomeTaskName /TR "schtasks /delete /TN SomeTaskName /F" /SC ONCE /ST 12:00
```

A kludgy solution I came up with that works is this:

```
schtasks /create /TN SomeTaskName /TR "notepad.exe" /SC MINUTE /MO 1 /ST 12:00 /ET 12:02 /Z
```

It has the side-effect of performing the task thrice before stopping.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to consider using Powershell since you're on Windows 10. I believe you can use `Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName applog -Confirm:$false` to delete a scheduled task without a confirmation prompt.

Someone else has reported a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29337135/powershell-v4-create-remote-task-scheduler-task-set-to-expire-and-delete), to which a user recommended adding `-Compatibility V1` (although I'm not sure if this still yields a user credential prompt).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that [but I have a new problem now](http://superuser.com/questions/1038579/task-scheduler-wont-allow-re-using-task-names-from-older-auto-deleted-tasks-th).

Answer (score 4):

The option `/z` does not work in conjunction with the start type `once`. If you use the option `/v1` the command executes without errors, but the task is not deleted after the next logon/execution.

To delete a task, Windows requires an expiration date, which is not possible with `once`.

You may delete the task 'manually', e.g. using something like this:

```
... /TR "cmd.exe /c notepad.exe && schtasks /delete /TN SomeTaskName /f" ...
```

This command executes `notepad.exe`, waits for its completition and if successfull deletes the task `SomeTaskName`. If you want to delete the task even in case of an error, just use a single `&`.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft suggests adding `/V1` to your command to work-around this issue.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2004151

This would give you:

```
schtasks /create /TN SomeTaskName /TR "notepad.exe" /SC ONCE /ST 12:00 /V1 /Z
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but I've already mentioned in my question that I am not keen on using this switch as doing so requires me to enter my password to schedule the task.

Comment: Sorry. I got reading the docs and forgot your V1 section! Given the odd XML error output from SCHTASKS compared to its usual output it looks like you have stumbled upon a bug.

Comment: I think I solved this issue but I don't remember how. It was quite a while ago. I'll post an answer if I remember what I did to get around this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use create a ScheduledJob with PowerShell. At the end of the job script, you can delete the job!.

```
Register-ScheduledJob -RunNow -Name "Archive-Scripts3"  -ScriptBlock {
  "test" | out-file -filepath c:\temp\test3.txt
  Get-ScheduledJob -Name "Archive-Scripts3" | Unregister-ScheduledJob -Force
}
```