# Task Scheduler won't allow re-use of task names from older, auto-deleted tasks that were created with the /Z switch

Tags: windows-10, windows-task-scheduler

While trying to [get this to work](https://superuser.com/q/1038528/167187) I created several scheduled tasks with the **`/Z`** switch which, according to documentation is...

> [A value that marks the task to be deleted after its final run.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357)

I was able to create scheduled tasks that were automatically deleted after they expired but I couldn't create new tasks with the same name thereafter. Here's a partial log of the commands I used:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>schtasks /create /TN testtask1 /TR calc.exe /SC ONCE /ST 20:06
SUCCESS: The scheduled task "testtask1" has successfully been created.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>schtasks /create /TN testtask1 /TR calc.exe /SC ONCE /ST 20:07 /F
SUCCESS: The scheduled task "testtask1" has successfully been created.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>schtasks /create /TN testtask1 /TR calc.exe /SC ONCE /ST 20:08 /F /Z
ERROR: The task XML is missing a required element or attribute.
(40,4):EndBoundary:
C:\WINDOWS\system32>schtasks /create /TN testtask1 /TR calc.exe /SC MINUTE /MO 1 /ST 20:09 /ET 20:11 /F /Z
SUCCESS: The scheduled task "testtask1" has successfully been created.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>schtasks /query /TN testtask1

Folder: \
TaskName                                 Next Run Time          Status
======================================== ====================== ===============
testtask1                                11-02-2016 20:11:00    Ready

C:\WINDOWS\system32>schtasks /query /TN testtask1
ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>schtasks /create /TN testtask1 /TR calc.exe /SC MINUTE /MO 1 /ST 20:12 /ET 20:14 /F /Z
ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>schtasks /create /TN testtask1 /TR calc.exe /SC MINUTE /MO 1 /ST 20:12 /ET 20:14 /Z
WARNING: The task name "testtask1" already exists. Do you want to replace it (Y/N)? y
ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I'm using **Windows 10 (Build 10586.104)** and I haven't tested this on older Windows versions so I'm not sure if this issue is specific to my system. I also can not use the GUI interface (`taskschd.msc`) to create scheduled tasks with previously used names.

On [@root's suggestion](https://superuser.com/a/1038569/167187), I tried running `Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName testtask1 -Confirm:$false` in PowerShell but that got me this error:

```
Unregister-ScheduledTask : No MSFT_ScheduledTask objects found with property 'TaskName' equal to 'testtask1'.  Verify
the value of the property and retry.
```

I also ran `fsutil resource setautoreset true c:\` and rebooted Windows as recommended by [aikitsupport.com](http://aikitsupport.com/task-scheduler-error-a-task-or-folder-with-this-name-already-exists/) but that didn't help either.

---

PS If you can think of a better question title, feel free to edit it.

Comment: Can you confirm if testtask1 exists once, more than once, or not at all with `Get-ScheduledTask | Sort-Object TaskName`? To be thorough, run in an elevated instance of PS

Comment: @root It doesn't show in the list. The relevant XML file doesn't show up in `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks` either. It did once, before the scheduled task executed and subsequently expired and the file was deleted. It won't show anymore.

Comment: Not that anyone should expect different results between `schtasks` and `Get-ScheduledTask`, but I think the format for the `/TN` parameter requires the full path to the task. Eg `schtasks /query /FO LIST /TN \Microsoft\Windows\Wininet\CacheTask` returns a result where `schtasks /query /FO LIST /TN CacheTask` does not. Also - just to be safe - if you're actually using calc.exe in your task and it is still running from when the task ran, close it.

Comment: @root omitting the full path gets you a result if a scheduled task with that name exists under the \ folder. No, `calc.exe` wasn't running. I closed it manually.

Comment: I can't replicate the problem, I am on Win 10 build 10586.71. Funny that in the log you posted, it shows the next run time for testtask1 equal to the end time you specified. Curious to see where you get with this.

Comment: You may have old testtask1 records in the TaskCache. I'd search for them here and delete any found: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tasks` and `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tree`

Comment: @root That did it! Thank you so much! The ***deleted*** tasks were listed under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tree` but not `..\Tasks` and after removing the relevant keys `schtasks.exe` stopped complaining. I wonder if this is a bug or just something that's only affecting my system. Nevertheless, please post it as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete non-valid entries from the TaskCache. The TaskCache is normally maintained automatically, in this case some entries were not removed automatically when the task was deleted.

Search in registry and manually delete any keys that contain the non-valid scheduled task name that are found in:

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tasks`

and

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tree`

This will allow reuse of the task name.

Other users with this scenario may also have to delete entries found in `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks` containing the task name, although in this case, you noticed these had already been deleted.